# SSH Swap ctrl and caps

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

On my machine I have ctrl and caps swapped however I frequently use other machines where I can not remap caps and ctrl. Is it possible to handle remapping on my vps.

I have tried various methods with no luck, dumpkeys/loadkeys don't work because it is not a real terminal, editing  /etc/default/keyboard also does not work.

Comment: All modifier keys (shift, ctrl, etc) are handled *locally* before being sent over an ssh connection. I swap ctrl and caps also, and never have any trouble when connecting to other machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any way to swap these two keys on the remote peer, since the terminal program on the *local* end will send a `H` rather than `caps-lock+h` packet to the remote peer when <kbd>caps lock</kbd> is on and <kbd>h</kbd> is pressed.